# bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR - load unsafe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this   [bootstrap style datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) 
datetime control works perfectly when the browser is enabled for load unsafe content,

However, if browser is disabled for load unsafe content, then static calender is visible at the end of the page,

Please suggest a better way to view datetime picker, as user has to enable load unsafe content each time they visit the page.

thank you

Comment: how about using HTML5 <input type='date' ... as an alternative solution?

Comment: Is your site running with SSL?

Comment: yes it is running with SSL